# S3 upload a directory and make its contents public

Tags: java, amazon-s3

Is there a way to upload a whole directory to S3 programmatically and set the contents of this directory to be publicly accessible? I used the following code to make the directory public:

```
s3client.setObjectAcl(bucket, prefixKey, CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead); // s3client is of type AmazonS3Client
```

Where prefixKey is the directory in S3  `e.g. /region/user` whoever when I try to access the files inside this directory, I still get access denial!

Do I have to make every object, inside this directory, public individually?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [TransferManager.uploadDirectory](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html#uploadDirectory%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File,%20boolean,%20com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.ObjectMetadataProvider%29), and use [ObjectMetadataProvider](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/ObjectMetadataProvider.html) to specify permission.

Comment: can u supply an example?

Comment: Here is an example in the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46348295/amazon-java-s3-sdk-uploaddirectory.